# Does a BroadcastReceiver only listen to changes?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, power-management

I was reading the guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) about setting up a `BroadcastReceiver` to check changes in the battery. And it stated that I could setup a `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in my manifest and this as a class:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    }
}
```

Is the `BroadcastReceiver` call `onReceive(...)` ONLY when a CHANGE occurs in the battery state? For example, what if the user had the device plugged into their computer and it was charging the entire time the `BroadcastReceiver` was running. Would it detect a change, since technically, the device's battery status didn't change? Whenever I get `isCharging`, would it be the current value, or the value at the last change? I want to check if it did change and what it always is so that I can optimize my application and save battery life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will get called only on these actions, as you specified...

1. `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`
2. `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`

And that's when...

1) *External power has been connected to the device.*

2) *External power has been removed from the device.*

If you need to track battery power changes, you should include this filter in your manifest.

`android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`

Btw.
`isCharging` would be the current state, of course.

Comment: So if I were to create a method like `public boolean isCharging()` and it returns `isCharging`. `isCharging()` can be called at anytime, so would it accurately return if the device was charging?

Comment: I believe (almost certain :)) it would. Why not testing it to be sure?

Comment: `isCharging` would correctly indicate charging status only if `onReceive` gets called just before you call `isCharging()`. You need to put your `isCharging` evaluation code in `isCharging()` method.

Comment: P.S I would create a helper class and would name it cleverly just for specific static methods. I wouldn't couple it with `BroadcastReceiver`, for the sake of good design.

Comment: @AljoshBre thanks for the tip, but the evaluation code is dependent on the `Intent` in the `onReceive`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `BroadcastReceiver` uses the **Publisher-Subscriber Pattern.**

**2.** Its used in this way..**" If xyz happens inform me, and i will take action on the basis of that".**

1. Its not only on the CHANGE in battery states, but many more, like When **Booting is completed etc...**

See this for more details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you want  put it in onCreate method**

```
BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
            int scale = -1;

            int level = -1;

            int voltage = -1;

            int temp = -1;

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {
                level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

                scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

                temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);

                voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);

                Log.e("BatteryManager", "level is "+level+"/"+scale+", temp is "+temp+", voltage is "+voltage);
            }    
        };

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);

            registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
```